# How can i set two background colours for a single row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to set two background colours for single row like in this image.[image]

The following is my code which is for array and below that there are tableView delegate methods.

```
 -(viewDidLoad)

 if([managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"] != nil)
{
    [_displayValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Personality    %@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]]];
}
 if([managedObject valueForKey:@"video_tag"] != nil)
{
    [_displayValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tag                 %@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"video_tag"]]];
}

 if([managedObject valueForKey:@"industry_master_values"] != nil)
{
    [_displayValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Industry       %@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"industry_master_values"]]];
}
 }
```

Here is tableView delegate methods

```
   - (NSArray *)myTableViewCells
 {
if (!_myTableViewCells)
 {
    _myTableViewCells = @[
                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],
                          [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil],

                          ];
 }

 return _myTableViewCells;
 }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {


return self->_displayValues.count;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
UITableViewCell* cell = self.myTableViewCells[indexPath.row];

     NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.devices lastObject];

      UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:900];

      [lbl setText:[managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]];

      lbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

      [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

return cell;
   }
```

Comment: gradient bg with more number of colors

Comment: are you set color on label

Comment: see the full code @balkaransingh

Comment: you can take 2 label set the background color . why you are useing  textLabel ?

Comment: yes tried using two labels but didn't work don't know how to do exactly  @balkaransingh

Comment: actually if i drag the outlets fromm the label in the .h file it gives me storyboard error saying outlets cannot be attached to the repeating content @balkaransingh

Comment: you can use tag number to access  label in cell .

Answer (score 2):

Set background color for labels or try to add two view inside of your table cell content view

## not enough repo to post as a comment

Comment: i had added a view inside content view on storyboard but it din't work

Answer (score 1):

Add subviews, use layout constraints to size the subviews, apply the background colour to each of the views.

It's possible that you could use the labels in the cell to do that without using additional views, you'd just need to set the constraints appropriately. It actually looks like it might be a background colour on the cell and a background colour on just one of the labels...

Comment: do i have to add subview in cell on storyboard.

Comment: you don't have to, but it's one of the options

Comment: i had added a view with blue background color like in image in content view but it din't help

Answer (score 0):

You should have to take two Labels in subview of UITableViewCell and give two different colors to them.

Write this in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    for(UIView *eachView in [cell subviews])
        [eachView removeFromSuperview];

    //Initialize Label
    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:YOURFRAME];
    [lbl1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:12.0]];
    [lbl1 setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    lbl1.text = YOUR CELL TEXT;
    [cell addSubview:lbl1];
    [lbl1 release];

    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:YOURFRAME];
    [lbl2 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:12.0]];
    [lbl2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    lbl2.text = YOUR CELL TEXT;
    [cel2 addSubview:lbl2];
    [lbl2 release];

    return cell;
}
```

If you are not familiar with customisation of UITableViewCell means if you dont know how to add two different labels in the subview of UITableViewCell, then [Follow this tutorial to customise your tableviewcell](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

plz take two label in uitableview cell and you can access them

```
 UILabel *label =(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:yourtagnumber];
```

[image]
set this identifier value , and set the style to custom

the in

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {
    UITableViewCell*  cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"youridentifier"];

         NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.devices lastObject];

          UILabel *lbl=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:900];

          [lbl setText:[managedObject valueForKey:@"personality_company_master_values"]];

          lbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];



    return cell;
       }
```

Comment: yes i have tried this way but i don't know why it was not showing see the 3 commented lines below in my code section

Comment: what the mena of this line UITableViewCell* cell = self.myTableViewCells[indexPath.row];

Comment: plz access your cell with   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"your idetifier"];

Comment: see the full code now this is the only code i am using full code, with  UITableViewCell* cell = self.myTableViewCells[indexPath.row]; line meaning

Comment: are you using  storyboard or not ?

Comment: but if i use the reusable cell with identifief the same value repeats in every cell which i don't want thats why i create the myTableViewCell  for setting each cell the value i wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117325/discussion-between-balkaran-singh-and-vicky).